# Changing size and position of svg map

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a map of my country, and I try to resize it so as not to take up so much space on the screen, but for some reason, whenever I try to do so, a part of the map is erased as if a square had removed that area, would anyone know how to fix that?

```
<svg xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     mapsvg:geoViewBox="-90.125247 14.450692 -87.683841 13.152442"
     width="792.89117"
     height="431.65646">...</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**size and position an `svg` image using a `div` container**

In this example, I've used an inline `svg` element to illustrate the use of a styled container `div` to position and size an `svg` image (your image won't load in the snippet tool so I've used an arbitrary image of my own).

The image has dimensions (specified as attributes of the `svg` opening tag) of 1200, 840px and renders at that size if used outside of an unrestrained container.

The image element is inside a `div` element of class `.container`. The container is styled to the required size in the style sheet (in this case 200x140px, keeping the aspect ratio of the original image size). In the style sheet, the `svg` element is sized to 100% for both `width` and `height` (these are relative to the container).

The position on the page is determined by the position of the container. In this example I've set the body to be a flex container and justified its contents to flex-end (to push the container and its image) to the right of the viewport.

This approach is adaptable to any inline svg element and is reliable.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

svg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}

div.container {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 200px;
height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="l2khr5eg" version="1.1" width="1200" height="840" viewBox="0 0 120 84" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="12" y="72.67826086956522" width="6.4" height="2.921739130434782" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>0.87% of total</title></rect><rect x="18.4" y="69.75652173913045" width="6.4" height="5.843478260869564" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>1.75% of total</title></rect><rect x="24.8" y="69.75652173913045" width="6.4" height="5.843478260869564" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>1.75% of total</title></rect><rect x="31.200000000000003" y="63.91304347826088" width="6.4" height="11.686956521739129" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>3.5% of total</title></rect><rect x="37.6" y="58.069565217391315" width="6.4" height="17.530434782608697" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>5.26% of total</title></rect><rect x="44" y="55.14782608695653" width="6.4" height="20.45217391304348" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>6.14% of total</title></rect><rect x="50.400000000000006" y="49.30434782608697" width="6.4" height="26.29565217391304" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>7.89% of total</title></rect><rect x="56.800000000000004" y="37.617391304347834" width="6.4" height="37.982608695652175" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>11.4% of total</title></rect><rect x="63.2" y="31.773913043478274" width="6.4" height="43.826086956521735" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>13.15% of total</title></rect><rect x="69.6" y="8.400000000000006" width="6.4" height="67.2" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>20.17% of total</title></rect><rect x="76" y="40.539130434782614" width="6.4" height="35.060869565217395" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>10.52% of total</title></rect><rect x="82.4" y="43.46086956521739" width="6.4" height="32.139130434782615" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>9.64% of total</title></rect><rect x="88.80000000000001" y="63.91304347826088" width="6.4" height="11.686956521739129" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>3.5% of total</title></rect><rect x="95.2" y="66.83478260869566" width="6.4" height="8.765217391304349" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>2.63% of total</title></rect><rect x="101.60000000000001" y="69.75652173913045" width="6.4" height="5.843478260869564" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2px" fill="brown" class="bar"><title>1.75% of total</title></rect><text text-anchor="start" x="12" y="3.3600000000000003" font-size="5.04" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">my data distribution</text><line x1="12" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="12" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="18.4" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="18.4" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="24.8" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="24.8" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="31.200000000000003" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="31.200000000000003" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="37.6" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="37.6" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="44" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="44" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="50.400000000000006" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="50.400000000000006" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="56.800000000000004" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="56.800000000000004" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="63.2" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="63.2" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="69.6" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="69.6" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="76" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="76" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="82.4" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="82.4" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="88.80000000000001" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="88.80000000000001" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="95.2" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="95.2" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="101.60000000000001" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="101.60000000000001" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><line x1="108" y1="75.60000000000001" x2="108" y2="76.944" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.4px"/><text text-anchor="middle" x="12" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-1</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="18.4" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.9</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="24.8" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.8</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="31.200000000000003" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.7</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="37.6" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.6</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="44" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.5</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="50.400000000000006" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.4</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="56.800000000000004" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.3</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="63.2" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.2</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="69.6" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">-0.1</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="76" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="82.4" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0.1</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="88.80000000000001" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0.2</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="95.2" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0.3</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="101.60000000000001" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0.4</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="108" y="81.312" font-size="2.016" font-family="Arial" fill="black" font-weight="lighter">0.5</text></svg></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the position and size with css.

`svg { width: 100px; height: 200px;}`

(makes the svg 100x200 px)

Comment: i tried it but for some reason the map disappear and just a little piece of the corner of the map shows